# calling function which is encrypted on dll file and that file is added as a reference in my sloution

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, dll

I have made one common libarary using c# (.dll file is created) that is having some common functions .

Now I have one solution which is having so many projects made on vb and c++ .

Now here I added that above dll file in this solution (by adding refrence).

and I want to access those common function from dll to this all projects .
Is this possible??
IF YES THEN HOW??

Comment: Cant you add the reference of the C# dll in all your vb or c++ projects as well?

Answer (score 0):

For each C++ and VB.NET project, right-click on References and add the C# project as a reference.

Then access your c# classes & methods as you would access thus from the .NET "built-in" libraries.

If it's not a project within your solution, then for each project, browse to the dll and add it that way.